# LINQ to objects -- need where clause with AND and OR conditions

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am a noob to LINQ and I have not been able to build a where clause that has multiple conditions.  Basically I need something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE location = @location AND (unitype = "L" OR unittype = "D")
```

Alternately:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE location = @location AND unitype IN ("D", "L")
```

I can do AND or OR, but I can't figure out how to do both in one statement.  My existing query is as follows.  It works, but doesn't limit by location.  I can successfully limit by location and a single unit type, but not both.  I'm not sure if I need a subquery or some other method -- a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
gvFixed.ItemsSource = from fs in fixedSystem
//where fs.Owner.Location.ToString() == location && (fs.UnitType == "D" || fs.UnitType == "L")
where fs.UnitType == "D" || fs.UnitType == "L"
group fs by new { fs.Owner.Name } into grouping
select new FixedSystem()
{
    Owner = new SystemOwner() { Name = grouping.Key.Name },
    OnHand = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.OnHand),
    FMC = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.FMC),
    NMCS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.NMCS),
    NMCM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.NMCM),
    PMCS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.PMCS),
    PMCM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.PMCM),
    FMCPercent = Math.Round(grouping.Average(fs => fs.FMCPercent)),
    ScheduleS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleS),
    ScheduleM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleM),
    ScheduleT = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleT)
};
```

Full text of error (results of the query are going into a Telerik data grid):

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 4004 
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. 
Must be non- negative and less than the size of the collection. 
Parameter name: index 
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource) 
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Windows.Data.KeyedCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableCollectionView.InternalGetItemAt(Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.Generator.GenerateNext(Boolean stopAtRealized, Boolean& isNewlyRealized) 
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.GenerateNext(Boolean& isNewlyRealized) 
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewVirtualizingPanel.GenerateNextChild(IItemContainerGenerator generator, Int32 childIndex) 
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewVirtualizingPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) 
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your commented where clause?

Comment: I get an error System.ArgumentOutofRangeException: Index was out of range.

Comment: I guess that error will be raised somewhere inside `fs.Owner.Location` or the evaluation of `location`. Have you tried to debug this issue in the debugger?

Comment: Evaluating the location works -- I can get the where clause to work with any 2 conditions (location + either unit type) but not with all 3.  Works on the data side, too... maybe it's not my data source but something in the controls on the page.

Comment: The question is: Where exactly is the exception raised (callstack)?

Comment: @Nicole, can you post a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Ok, exception is thrown somewhere in your telerik GridView while accessing a data item. What is `fixedSystem`? Can you try to assign the select to a local variable (and not the gridview property)? And add a `.ToList()` call to be sure that the query is not deferred.

Comment: Try inspecting your results manually while debugging without databinding to make sure your query is returinging what you think it is. I suspect the exception is occuring in binding or one of your values.

Comment: Thanks, ya'll.  I will check these when I am back in the office on Monday and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long to get back to his; other projects at the office interfered.  Here's the solution:

```
gvFixed.ItemsSource = from fs in fixedSystem
where (fs.UnitType == "D" || fs.UnitType == "L") && fs.Owner.Location.ToString() == item.Name
group fs by fs.FixedType into grouping
select new FixedSystem()
{
    Owner = new SystemOwner(),
    FixedType = grouping.Key,
    OnHand = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.OnHand),
    FMC = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.FMC),
    NMCS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.NMCS),
    NMCM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.NMCM),
    PMCS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.PMCS),
    PMCM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.PMCM),
    FMCPercent = Math.Round(grouping.Average(fs => fs.FMCPercent)),
    ScheduleS = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleS),
    ScheduleM = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleM),
    ScheduleT = grouping.Sum(fs => fs.ScheduleT)
};
```

I had to explicity put the FixedType property into the selected object.  It makes sense in hindsight but it didn't seem necessary to specify an already defined property when I initially wrote the statement.